# Upload a picture with a php function

Tags: php, function, input

It's the first time I'm trying to create a function and I can't figure it out...
I'm trying to build a function who will upload a picture and return her path, but the echo doesn't display anything andI don't have any syntaxe error tho... I don't really understand?

I hope you may see more clearer than me.

function.inc.php:

```
function upload_photo(
$photo_input_name, $photo_path, $photo_type1, $photo_type2, $photo_max_weight, $photo_max_height, $photo_max_width)
{

if (isset($_FILES[$photo_input_name]))
{

    //UPLOAD DE FICHIER
    if(!empty($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']))
    { //si n'est pas vide

        //spécification du chemin d'enregistrement
        $dossier = $photo_path;

        if (exif_imagetype($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']) != $photo_type1 AND exif_imagetype($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']) != $photo_type2)
        { //si le format de l'image est différent de jpg ou png                         
            $erreur = 'Oups, extension non reconnu. Les extensions autorisées sont '.$photo_type1.' '.$photo_type2.'.';
        }

        else 
        { //si l'image est un jpg ou png

            //on défini le poid max et on appel le poid de l'image uploader
            $max_weight = $photo_max_weight;
            $weight = filesize($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']);

            if ($weight > $max_weight)
            { // si le poid de l'image est supérieur au poid max autorisé                   
                unlink($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']); 
                $erreur = 'Oups, le fichier est trops volumineux, il ne doit pas depasser '.$photo_max_weight.' mo.';
            }

            else
            { // si le poid de l'image est inférieur ou egal on continue                    
                $max_height = $photo_max_height;
                $max_width = $photo_max_width;
                $photo_size = getimagesize($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']);

                if ($photo_size == FALSE)
                { // si les informations récuperer par la fonction getimagesize ne sont pas valide, 
                    // le fichier n'est pas une image, on le supprime et affiche une erreur
                    unlink($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']); 
                    $erreur = 'Oups, il semble que le fichier ne soit pas valide.';
                }

                if ($photo_size[1] != $max_height AND $photo_size[0] != $max_width)
                { // si les dimensions de l'image sont differentes de $photo_max_width/height, 
                 // on efface l'image uploader et on affiche une erreur
                    unlink($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']);
                    $erreur = 'Oups, il semble que l\'image ne soit pas au bon format ('.$max_width.' x '.$max_height.' px).';
                }

                if (!isset($erreur))
                { // si il n'y a aucune erreur on continue vers l'enregistrement

                    if (is_file($dossier.$_FILES[$photo_input_name]['name']))
                    {// si il y a un fichier du même nom dans le dossier on lui ajoute un prefix

                        $file_upload = rand (0, 15).'_'.$_FILES[$photo_input_name]['name'];

                        $fichier = $file_upload;
                    }

                    else $file_upload = $_FILES[$photo_input_name]['name'];

                    $fichier = $file_upload;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier)) 
                    { //si l'image est uploader
                        echo $dossier.$fichier;
                        return true;        
                    }
                }

                else 
                { //si l'upload echoue

                    $erreur = 'Oups, la copie de la photo sur le serveur a échoué';

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

}
```

And the page where I'm trying to use my function:

```
if (isset($_FILES)) 
{   
    include('function.inc.php');

    $photo_input_name = 'photo_buste_coeurG_'.$line;
    $photo_path = '../../images/uploaded/';
    $photo_type1 = 'IMAGETYPE_JPEG';
    $photo_type2 = 'IMAGETYPE_PNG';
    $photo_max_weight = 1048576;
    $photo_max_height = 480;
    $photo_max_width = 480;


    upload_photo($photo_input_name, $photo_path, $photo_type1, $photo_type2, $photo_max_weight, $photo_max_height, $photo_max_width);


}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried echoing values step by step through the function to see where it is breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if ($photo_size[1] != $max_height AND $photo_size[0] != $max_width)
```

You only allow photos that are *exactly* `$max_height` high and *exactly* `$max_width` wide. Those `!=` should be `>`. Also, the `AND` should `OR` (or `||`, which is more commonly used)

Also `IMAGETYPE_JPEG` and `IMAGETYPE_PNG` are constants, you should use them as such, not put that value in a string; it doesn't work.

While we're here, allow me to comment on how the function is set up.
There are a few structural problems in your code.

- You are assigning variables the value of other variables quite often, which is quite confusing and unnecessary.
- You are constantly doing if ... then ... else which is making the code overly complex. Just if it is not, and then return (or, better, throw an Exception).
- You are limiting yourself to two photo types. What if you ever want to remove on of them? What if you ever want to add one? You need to go through all your code and replace the function calls. Instead, use an array so you can give an arbitrary number of options.

For reference, this is how I would write your function

```
// the function is called upload_photo, no need to prepend photo to each and every argument
function upload_photo($input_name, $path, array $types, $max_weight, $max_height, $max_width)
{
    if (empty($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']))
    {
        throw new Exception('No file uploaded');
    }

    $type = exif_imagetype($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']);
    if (!in_array($type, $types))
    { //si le format de l'image est différent de jpg ou png                         
        throw new Exception('Oups, extension non reconnu. Les extensions autorisées sont '.implode(',', $types).'.');
    }

    $weight = filesize($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']);
    if ($weight > $max_weight)
    { // si le poid de l'image est supérieur au poid max autorisé                   
        unlink($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']); 
        throw new Exception('Oups, le fichier est trops volumineux, il ne doit pas depasser '.($max_weight / 1024 / 1024).' mo.');
    }

    $photo_size = getimagesize($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']);
    if ($photo_size == FALSE)
    { // si les informations récuperer par la fonction getimagesize ne sont pas valide, 
        // le fichier n'est pas une image, on le supprime et affiche une erreur
        unlink($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']); 
        throw new Exception('Oups, il semble que le fichier ne soit pas valide.');
    }
    if ($photo_size[1] > $max_height || $photo_size[0] > $max_width)
    { // si les dimensions de l'image sont differentes de $photo_max_width/height, 
     // on efface l'image uploader et on affiche une erreur
        unlink($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name']);
        throw new Exception('Oups, il semble que l\'image ne soit pas au bon format ('.$max_width.' x '.$max_height.' px).');
    }

    if (file_exists($path.$_FILES[$photo_input_name]['name']))
    {// si il y a un fichier du même nom dans le dossier on lui ajoute un prefix
        // FIXME: What if the renamed file also already exists? -- left as an exercise for the reader
        $fichier = rand (0, 15).'_'.$_FILES[$photo_input_name]['name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $fichier = $_FILES[$photo_input_name]['name'];
    }

    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$photo_input_name]['tmp_name'], $path . $fichier)) 
    { //cannot move file
        throw new Exception('Oups, la copie de la photo sur le serveur a échoué');        
    }

    return $dossier.$fichier;
}
```

and then this is how you would call it

```
if (isset($_FILES)) 
{   
    include('function.inc.php');

    $input_name = 'photo_buste_coeurG_'.$line;
    $path = '../../images/uploaded/';
    $types = array(IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG);
    $max_weight = 1048576;
    $max_height = 480;
    $max_width = 480;

    try {
        upload_photo($input_name, $path, $types, $max_weight, $max_height, $max_width);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Erreur: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, you've been really clear, thanks you for your concision and the time you'd take for being pedagogic.
I didn't knew Exceptions, could I possibly pass or catch an Exception through an url?
I have one more question, / 1024 / 1024 will display 1, but if I'm setting the max_weight var to 5120 for exemple, how could I get 5 from this?
Thank you again!

Comment: 5120 byte != 5Mb, so I don't see why you want to display it like that. If you want to show 5Kb, do `5120/1024`, or (`floor(5120/1024)` to get to a round number).